# Save View to Image

Tags: java, android, view

I have this class and I want to save my drawing to a jpeg file when the actionbar is clicked.

```
public class SingleTouchActivity extends Activity {


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));

    // Create ActionBar
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.show();

  }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // ActionBar is clicked
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.sig_reset:
            finish();
            Intent sigIntent = new Intent(this, SingleTouchActivity.class);
            startActivity(sigIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.sig_save:
            //Save to image
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I searched the web and I found this code snippet:

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, new FileOutputStream("/some/location/image.jpg"));
```

And this one:

```
//createBitmap(int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)
//    Returns a mutable bitmap with the specified width and height.
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(mapRelativeView.getWidth(), mapRelativeView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

//draw(Canvas canvas) -- Manually render this view
//(and all of its children) to the given Canvas.
yourView.draw(new Canvas(image));

//insertImage(ContentResolver cr, Bitmap source, String title, String description)
//    Insert an image and create a thumbnail for it.
//uri is the path after the image has been saved.
String uri = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), image, "title", null);
```

The problem is that my SingleTouchActivity set's SingleTouchEventView as content, and I don't know how I have to define my view.

Comment: so its free hand drawing or anything else ?

Comment: see my Answer and check it and get back to me

Answer (score 1):

This is Free Hand Draw Example where you can draw anything and save as image in SD Card.

DownLoad Full Source Form [Here](https://sites.google.com/site/khetiyachintan/SigntuareCapture.rar?attredirects=0&d=1)

This is main **OnCreate()** method where that **perform some specific task**.

```
Like :
```

- Check path is Exist if no then Set Image Path .
- Set Image Name as per current Date & Time.
- prepare Screen View.
- Draw Signature.
- Store in SD Card.
- Return to Activity with Bitmap Image so it can be set on Image View.
- Clear Drawable  Signature.

  ```
     @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  setContentView(R.layout.signature);

  // tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +   getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir) + "/";
   ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
  // File directory = cw.getDir(getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir),  Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Your_Floder_Name");
  ```

**Check path is Exist if no then Set Image Path .**

```
if(!directory.exists())

directory.mkdir(); //directory is created;

//prepareDirectory();
```

**Set Image Name as per current Date & Time.**

```
uniqueId = getTodaysDate() + "_" + getCurrentTime();
current = uniqueId + ".png";
mypath= new File(directory,current);

mContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
```

**Draw Signature**

```
mSignature = new signature(this, null);
mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

**prepare Screen View.**

```
mContent.addView(mSignature, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

**Clear Drawable  Signature.**

```
mClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
mGetSign = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getsign);
mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
mCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
mView = mContent;
```

**Clear Drawable  Signature.**

```
mClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

{
public void onClick(View v)
{
Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Cleared");
mSignature.clear();
mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
}
});
```

**Draw Signature**

```
mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View v)
{
Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
// boolean error = captureSignature();
// if(error){
mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
mSignature.save(mView);
//Bundle b = new Bundle();
// b.putString("status", "done");
Intent intent = new Intent(Capture.this,SigntuareCaptureActivity.class);
// intent.putExtra("imagePath",mypath);
startActivity(intent);
//intent.putExtra("status", "done");
//setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
// }
}
});
```

**Cancel if Don't want to Draw Signature.**

```
mCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View v)
{
Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Canceled");
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("status", "cancel");
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtras(b);
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
}
});

}
```

**Set Image Name With Current Date & Time.**

```
private String getTodaysDate()

{

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int todaysDate = (c.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 10000) +
((c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) * 100) +
(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
Log.w("DATE:",String.valueOf(todaysDate));
return(String.valueOf(todaysDate));

}

private String getCurrentTime()
{

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentTime = (c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 10000) +
(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 100) +
(c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
Log.w("TIME:",String.valueOf(currentTime));
return(String.valueOf(currentTime));

}
```

**Check Your Directory if Not Exist then Create New**

```
private boolean prepareDirectory()
{
try
{
if (makedirs())
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
Toast.makeText(this, "Could not initiate File System.. Is Sdcard mounted properly?", 1000).show();
return false;
}
}

private boolean makedirs()
{
File tempdir = new File(tempDir);
if (!tempdir.exists())
tempdir.mkdirs();

if (tempdir.isDirectory())
{
File[] files = tempdir.listFiles();
for (File file : files)
{
if (!file.delete())
{
System.out.println("Failed to delete " + file);
}
}
}
return (tempdir.isDirectory());
}
```

**Draw your Signature**

```
public class signature extends View
{
private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();

private float lastTouchX;
private float lastTouchY;
private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

public signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
super(context, attrs);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
}

public void save(View v)
{
Log.v("log_tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
Log.v("log_tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
if(mBitmap == null)
{
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap (mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
}
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
try
{

FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

v.draw(canvas);
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
mFileOutStream.flush();
mFileOutStream.close();
String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title", null);
//Log.v("log_tag","url: " + url);

// //In case you want to delete the file
// boolean deleted = mypath.delete();
// Log.v("log_tag","deleted: " + mypath.toString() + deleted);
// //If you want to convert the image to string use base64 converter

}
catch(Exception e)
{
Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
}
}

public void clear()
{
path.reset();
invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
float eventX = event.getX();
float eventY = event.getY();
mGetSign.setEnabled(true);

switch (event.getAction())
{
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
lastTouchX = eventX;
lastTouchY = eventY;
return true;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++)
{
float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
}
path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
break;

default:
debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
return false;
}

invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
(int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
(int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
(int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

lastTouchX = eventX;
lastTouchY = eventY;

return true;
}

private void debug(String string)
{
}

private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY)
{
if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left)
{
dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
}
else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right)
{
dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
}

if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top)
{
dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
}
else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom)
{
dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
}
}

private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY)
{
dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
}
}
```

**How to call this class ?**

**on Click of button in main Activity** ,

```
your_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View view)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(SigntuareCaptureActivity.this, Capture.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();

}
});
```